# Returned dtype of numpy vectorized function

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have an issue regarding the dtype of the returned numpy array of a vectorized function. My function returns a number, eventually a fraction. Strangely the position of the fraction seems to influence the returned dtype. I want the type always to be `object` if the function returns a fraction.

```
import numpy as np
from fractions import Fraction

foo = lambda x: Fraction(1, 3) if x < 0.5 else 1
foo_vectorized = np.vectorize(foo)

foo_vectorized([1, 0.3]) # returns array([1, 0])
foo_vectorized([0.3, 1]) # returns array([Fraction(1, 3), 1], dtype=object)
```

Is this a bug or is it expected to work like this? I use numpy 1.9.2 on Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6.

Thanks for any explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is exactly as the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) states:

"The output type is determined by evaluating the first element of the input, unless it is specified."

You can specify the desired output type via the `otypes` arg, e.g.:

```
 np.vectorize(foo, otypes=[np.object])
```

Answer (score 1):

This forces the return value to be an `object`:

```
foo_vectorized = np.vectorize(foo, otypes=[object])
```